# Multiple videos embedded on Firefox 17.0.1

Tags: html, firefox, iframe

I'm having issues with firefox 17.0.1 on a Windows OS on loading multiple Vimeo videos.

It's a weird bug that I cannot figure out, it only seems to be able to replicated using this operating system and browser.

The problem is there are many videos embedded using Vimeo, and it only seems to load the first two videos, then a little more down the page it loads some black boxes.

Just wondering if anyone else has the same issue, and a possible fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Firefox *intentionally* runs only Flash objects that are visible (and runs other ones *when* they become visible during scrolling). This is for performance reasons.

Comment: Is there anyway in the html to force it to load completely, just when running firefox?

Comment: Unlikely. Though, you can try to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) as a special solution to embed Flash — maybe it has some workaround for the issue. Also, it's logical to expect that making Flash object visible for some short time will automatically run it, and then you can hide it again, and the object probably will keep running. By the way, it always makes sense to [make sure](https://www.mozilla.org/ru/plugincheck/) you have latest version of Flash plugin.